# How to skip this generic object error in compile time

Tags: java

I want to initialize an "Object o" in class A and later in runtime set it to another type of object. Later, call the method of the object that it became, which is called with the same name in the B and C classes.

```
public class A {

   Object o;

   public void setB() {
      o = new B();
   }

   public void getC() {
      o = new C();
   }

   public void use() {
      o.do();
   }

}

public class B {
    public void do(){
      //do something
   }
}

public class C {
    public void do() {
       //do something
    }
}
```

I've tried with class extension but I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: You need to cast the object to another type first in your use method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the code below. You will be having an abstract class **BaseClass** having an abstract method **someMethod**. And your class B and C will extend the BaseClass and have their own implementation of method **someMethod**.

```
public class A {

    BaseClass o;

    public void setB() {
        o = new B();
    }

    public void getC() {
        o = new C();
    }

    public void use() {
        o.someMethod();
    }

}

public class B extends BaseClass {
    public void someMethod(){
        //do something
    }
}

public class C extends BaseClass {
    public void someMethod() {
        //do something
    }
}

public abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract void someMethod();
}
```

Or you can achieve the same using interface like the one follows.

```
public class A {

    AnInterface o;

    public void setB() {
        o = new B();
    }

    public void getC() {
        o = new C();
    }

    public void use() {
        o.someMethod();
    }

}

public class B implements AnInterface {
    public void someMethod() {
        //do something
    }
}

public class C implements AnInterface {
    public void someMethod() {
        //do something
    }
}

public interface AnInterface {
    public void someMethod();
}
```